# Jenkins: adding CUSTOM variables for a build

Tags: android, git, maven, jenkins

Jenkins successfully create build for Android and then uploads to an S3 server. The build contains environment name, version number that is different for each build. These version number, environments are read from POM profiles. An example URL of s3 http://example.com/android/staging/ABC-Project-v0.1.58-staging-aligned.apk

I get the file name by this

```
cd $WORKSPACE/target/
FILE_NAME=$(echo *aligned.apk)
```

So my link will be `http://example.com/dev/FILE_NAME`

But this is only visible in shell script. I want to use this in an email template so that the Software test engineers can access it. I was looking for a way in which I can temporarily assign this value to a variable and then put that in the email template.

Email template is:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>$PROJECT_NAME</h3>
<h4>Build #$BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS</h4>
<h4>${CAUSE}</h4>
<h4>$DEFAULT_CONTENT</h4>
<h4>Git Branch: ${GIT_BRANCH}</h4>

Changes since the last build:

${CHANGES}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the email step is a *later* part of the Jenkins build process, you'll need to use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). From its own example use cases you can: *inject variables as a build step obtained from a file filled in by a previous build step*.

You could set these when parsing your POM (either in Maven directly, or you could parse it manually with something like a build step using the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) and XmlSlurper (we do this actually)), and then they'd be available as environment variables (e.g. `$CHANGES`, `$CAUSE` etc) for your email templater script later on.

Comment: So you mean I have to put that FILE_NAME into a file when processing pom file. and later own I have to read and parse it and assign that value to be used in email template?

Comment: That's another way of doing it, but using that plugin is easier, as any environment variables you set in your earlier step (e.g. that script that runs as part of your Maven step), can be passed on to later steps (e.g. your email script). See the [EnvInject docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) for more details...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm about to offer two things that are kind of ugly but working perfect:
In both you can put the output (the link you want) in a /tmp/job.output.tmp file and then:

- use the post build task plugin - when the work ERROR or EXCEPTION or whatever you want is there, run sendEmail from bash to the people you want with the context of the file.
  a little bash and everything is great.
- this is probably more nice: use the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin editable mail notification to send your users the console output / the file in zip / not zipped as you like when the build fails / stable again and such. They have so much options..